# Pourquoi « avoir la pêche »?

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

Je me demande pourquoi on utilise le mot pêche pour dire qu'on se sent en pleine forme, etc.
[Wikipedia, à ce jour](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_la_p%C3%AAche), déclare qu'on ne sait pas, et que l'expression dériverait  d'« avoir la frite ».

Comment en est-on venu à choisir la pêche ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plusieurs spéculations sont avancées pour l'origine de l'expression « avoir la pêche ».

La *pêche* est un fruit très ancien originaire de Chine et [*dans la tradition taoïste, la pêche est un symbole d'immortalité*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%AAcher#Le_p.C3.AAcher_dans_la_tradition_culturelle_d.27Asie_Orientale). Donc quand on « a la pêche », on est tellement plein de vitalité qu'on devient immortel.

Les autres suppositions concernent aussi bien l'expression « avoir la pêche », que son synonyme « avoir la patate ». *Pêche* et *patate* sont tous les deux employés de façon familière pour désigner un coup de poing violent (*[patate](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patate)* et *[pêche](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%AAche#Nom_commun_1)*).
De là on dit d'un boxeur qui cogne avec force qu'il « a de la pêche » ou qu'il « a la patate », s'il frappe avec force, c'est donc qu'il a la pleine forme.

[Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-la-frite-la-patate.php), quant à lui renvoie à l'emploie familier de patate pour désigner la tête et dit que celui qui « est en bonne forme a une bonne 'patate' ».

À signaler que l'expression « avoir la frite » n'est qu'un dérivé d'« avoir la patate » et qu'elle est plus récente d'emploi. (Jacques Cellard - *Dictionnaire du français conventionnel* signale l'apparition d'« avoir la frite » en 1970).

Answer (score 0):

Être plein d'énergie et d'entrain, être en forme.

La vérité est la suivante : l'origine de cette expression est assez floue. Pour certains, elle viendrait de la culture chinoise pour qui la pêche est signe d'immortalité et de bonne santé. Pour d'autres, elle viendrait du monde de la boxe et de l'expression « avoir de la pêche » qui signifie avoir beaucoup de force.

Comment: Nous avons l'habitude sur French Language de citer nos sources et de mettre en évidence les citations.  En l’occurrence  : http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/13997/avoir-la-peche/

Comment: okay merci  la prochaine fois je mettrai aussi la source

Comment: It's not too late for references :-P Diverse answers are great!